# Are ASCII escape sequences and control characters parings part of a standard?

Tags: linux, unicode, terminal, ascii, posix

There are common pairings of escape sequences to ASCII control characters, such as Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Z to ETX and SUB, respectively.

On the Wikipedia [Control Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_(ASCII_and_derivatives)) page, there are most pairings, but no cited reference.

Are the control character and key sequence pairings part of a standard?

Where is that listed for Linux and other OS's?

Are there man pages listing these pairings?

**References**

- The Linux [manpage for termios(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/termios.3.html) lists *some* of them.
- the command `stty -a` lists *some* for your system

Comment: These are not standardized. [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html) which special key functions exist for terminal input, but does not require that e.g. INTR must default to Ctrl+C

Comment: it infuriates me that this is downvoted. Not feeling welcome here. Especially bc this is a really tricky topic of standards, convention, and common practice. There are people that figure this stuff out for a living. Why am I penalized for asking????!!!! Drive-by down-votes don't help!

Comment: I agree :|  I can see why someone would feel it would fall under "recommendation for off-site resource", "too broad" or "belongs on Linux/Unix SE" or similar, but the appropriate action for those is a close/migrate vote and not a downvote.

Comment: an upvote for an upvote; know what I mean ;)

Comment: Multi-posted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/443484/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a document in 1984 that summarizes ANSI Codes X3.64-1979, ANSI X3.4-1977, and ANSI X3.41-1974. This [ansicode.txt](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/ansicode.txt) describes how the control codes affect DEC LA-series hardcopy terminals and the VT-series video terminals.

Comment: That is the key bit, as well as the fly in the ointment.. they are terminal dependent. Glad to know there are other old-timers around.

Answer (score 0):

No standard required. It's just a notation. The leading `^` indicates that the special characters are being named. ^A is 0x01, ^B is 0x02, ... ^M is 0x0D, ... ^Z is 0x1A.

Comment: yes it's a notation. I'm asking about the common pairings and where they were established. Are they established by the ASCII standard? or another standard?